# How do I make my code perform a random function

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, scripting

I want my code to randomize between three different functions:

```
private void BackPack1()
{
    Player.Skin.SetComponent((PedComponent)3, 3, 0);
}

private void BackPack2()
{
    Player.Skin.SetComponent((PedComponent)3, 3, 1);
}

private void BackPack3()
{
    Player.Skin.SetComponent((PedComponent)3, 3, 2);
}
```

Is there an easy way?

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now, I couldn't get this function working correctly, I am just learning this stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private static Random r = new Random();

private void BackPack() {
    int i = r.Next(0,3);
    Player.Skin.SetComponent((PedComponent)3, 3, i); 
}
```

Only the last argument of your method call changed, so I assumed you wanted to randomize that argument.

Comment: Why make the Random object static?  The empty constructor will seed it with a time-based value anyway.  </NITPICK>

Comment: To ensure that two objects generated at the same time, will not generate the same 'random' values.

And it's cheaper.

Comment: In this context, who cares if two objects generate the same values? You only have three possibilities anyway.

Comment: There's always the change that this code is used in a piece of code and changed to support more possibilites. This way that scenario will work better.

Comment: In the greater scheme of things, makes zero difference either way.

Answer (score 3):

This code randomly calls one of the BackPack*X* functions

```
Action[] methods = new Action[] { BackPack1, BackPack2, BackPack3 };
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.Next(3);
Action method = methods[index];
method();
```